# oracle is replacing inverted question mark when i use hyphen i.e (–)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

While inserting a row into database that is oracle, it is behaving differently, we have two different oracle databases. in one database is working properly in another when I run the insert statement it it is inserting "¿" instead of "–".

example:

```
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE VALUES('Tes1', 'TestA – TestB');
```

it is inserted as TestA ¿ TestB.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Did you close the opening ' after TestB?

Comment: What are the character sets of these database? Check with `SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
    WHERE PARAMETER LIKE 'NLS%CHARACTERSET';`

Comment: hi jarlh,   character sets of these database is :: NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P15 0
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16 0